# Approximate the solutions as a series

Tags: equation-solving, series-expansion, approximation

I would like to solve the following equation $y^2=x^2+ax^2y^2+by^2x^3+cy^3x^2$ where $a,b,c$ are small, so $y\approx x+O(x^3)$. I would like to have a series approximation of the solution rather than an exact one, i.e. like $y=x+c_1x^3+c_2x^4+...$.

Is there a default function in mathematica that does that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick-and-dirty solution:

```
y^2 - (x^2 + a x^2 y^2 + b y^2 x^3 + c y^3 x^2) /. 
       y -> x + c1 x^2 + c2 x^3 + c3 x^4 + O[x]^5 // FullSimplify
Solve[% == 0, {c1, c2, c3}]
y -> x + c1 x^2 + c2 x^3 + c3 x^4 + O[x]^5 /. % // TeXForm
```

> $$y\to x+\frac{a x^3}{2}+\frac{1}{2} (b+c) x^4+O\left(x^5\right)$$

Compare to the exact solution:

```
FullSimplify[
    Series[
        Solve[y^2 - (x^2 + a x^2 y^2 + b y^2 x^3 + c y^3 x^2) == 0, y][[3, 1, 2]]
    , {x, 0, 4}],
c > 0
]
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I'm new to mathematica, would you briefly explain to me the difference between your two methods? and what does the [3,1,2] mean?

Comment: [[3,1,2]] accesses a nested list. On the first level the 3rd element, on the next level the 1st element and and the 3rd level the 2nd element. In C++ it would look like this: x[3][1][2]

Answer (score 5):

Could use implicit differentiation, solve for all derivatives at `x==0`.

```
ee = y^2 - (x^2 + a x^2 y^2 + b y^2 x^3 + c y^3 x^2) /. y -> y[x];
dpolys = Table[D[ee, {x, j}], {j, 0, 5}] /. x -> 0

(* {y[0]^2, 2*y[0]*Derivative[1][y][0], -2 - 2*a*y[0]^2 - 2*c*y[0]^3 + 
     2*Derivative[1][y][0]^2 + 2*y[0]*Derivative[2][y][0], 
   -6*b*y[0]^2 - 12*a*y[0]*Derivative[1][y][0] - 
  18*c*y[0]^2*Derivative[1][y][0] + 
     6*Derivative[1][y][0]*Derivative[2][y][0] + 
  2*y[0]*Derivative[3][y][0], 
   -48*b*y[0]*Derivative[1][y][0] + 6*Derivative[2][y][0]^2 - 
     12*a*(2*Derivative[1][y][0]^2 + 2*y[0]*Derivative[2][y][0]) - 
     12*c*(6*y[0]*Derivative[1][y][0]^2 + 
     3*y[0]^2*Derivative[2][y][0]) + 
     8*Derivative[1][y][0]*Derivative[3][y][0] + 
  2*y[0]*Derivative[4][y][0], 
   -60*b*(2*Derivative[1][y][0]^2 + 2*y[0]*Derivative[2][y][0]) + 
     20*Derivative[2][y][0]*Derivative[3][y][0] - 
     20*a*(6*Derivative[1][y][0]*Derivative[2][y][0] + 
          2*y[0]*Derivative[3][y][0]) - 
  20*c*(6*Derivative[1][y][0]^3 + 
          18*y[0]*Derivative[1][y][0]*Derivative[2][y][0] + 
          3*y[0]^2*Derivative[3][y][0]) + 
  10*Derivative[1][y][0]*Derivative[4][y][0] + 
     2*y[0]*Derivative[5][y][0]} *)

soln = Solve[dpolys == 0]

(* Out[139]= {{y[0] -> 0, Derivative[1][y][0] -> -1, 
  Derivative[2][y][0] -> 0, 
     Derivative[3][y][0] -> -3*a, Derivative[4][y][0] -> 12*(-b + c)}, 
   {y[0] -> 0, Derivative[1][y][0] -> 1, Derivative[2][y][0] -> 0, 
     Derivative[3][y][0] -> 3*a, Derivative[4][y][0] -> 12*(b + c)}} *)
```

So two solutions, both getting up to the fourth order term. We create a table, then use the solutions to fill in values and recast as a Taylor polynomial for each solution branch.

```
derivs = Table[D[y[x], {x, j}], {j, 0, 4}] /. x -> 0;
derivs.(x^Range[0, 4]/Factorial[Range[0, 4]]) /. soln

(* Out[142]= {-x - (a x^3)/2 + 1/2 (-b + c) x^4, 
 x + (a x^3)/2 + 1/2 (b + c) x^4} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

Substitute $y=xu$ to handle the node at the origin, differentiate and use [`AsymptoticDSolveValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticDSolveValue.html):

```
x * AsymptoticDSolveValue[{
    D[y^2 == (x^2 + a x^2 y^2 + b y^2 x^3 + c y^3 x^2) /. 
       y -> x * u[x] // Simplify[#, x != 0] &, x],
    u[0] == 1}, u[x], {x, 0, 3}] // Collect[#, x] &
```

> $$x+ \frac{a x^3}{2}+\frac{1}{2} x^4 (b+c)$$

Answer (score 1):

The new in M12 function [`AsymptoticSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticSolve) can be used to find the series:

```
AsymptoticSolve[y^2 == x^2 + a x^2 y^2 + b y^2 x^3 + c y^3 x^2, {y, 0}, {x, 0, 4}]
```

> {{y -> -x - (a x^3)/2 + 1/2 (-b + c) x^4}, {y -> 
>      x + (a x^3)/2 + 1/2 (b + c) x^4}}